# AS3 - My animated object is too detailed, it crashes flash if I run with more than 1 on the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a Movieclip for a soldier, who can load, aim and fire a rifle.  The animations work fine, but if I put 2 or more of them on the stage, when I run it it immediately crashes flash.

Is there any way to reduce the quality of the Movieclip so that I can have multiple soldiers on the screen without it crashing flash?

I am making a game which requires at least 40-50 of them to be on the screen at once.

Thanks.

Comment: Any stack-trace for this one? What exactly do you mean by "crashes flash"?
If you want to have like 40-50 of them you should consider using blitting/caching.

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript compiled by external soft crashes when uses symbols with set to false "visibility" attribute after adding this symbol to the stage. But when you compile same code in Flash IDE nothing happens. It's very hard to find.

Try to make all layers except one inactive by setting them "guide" type. Trying one by one you can find this violator layer and faster find sub symbol with switched off visibility.